# For Loops in c. Showing Final Result only

Tags: c

I wrote a simple C Program =>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, i;

    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++);
    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting ***OUTPUT*** as 6. why isn't it is printing command I gave in each iteration. it is Printing final results.

Comment: The 'body' of your `for` loop is the empty statement `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++);
                          ^
```

Here you have accidentally left a semicolon at the end of the for loop. The for loop effectively does nothing aside from incrementing `i`. By removing the semicolon, the for loop would work as expected. Additionally I recommend *always* using brackets on for loops or any construct that allows you to skip brackets (`if`, `while`, etc) for one-liners.

Comment: Thanq it worked